# Vagrant rsync doesn't remove deleted files

Tags: vagrant

If I delete a file on my local machine, it doesn't delete on vagrant when I rsync.

If I move a file on my local machine, it creates a new file in the new location on vagrant and keeps a copy at the old location. (I assume this is because moving a file is like deleting it and remaking it in a new location).

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Why is the default behavior to ignore deleted files on rsync?

How can I tell vagrant to delete files on rsync that I have deleted?

Answer (score 0):

[per documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html)

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine
>   running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

so when you make changes from your host you need to tell about the guest to sync again so you can run `vagrant rsync` again.

you can also run [`vagrant rsync-auto`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/rsync-auto.html)

> This command watches all local directories of any rsync synced folders
>   and automatically initiates an rsync transfer when changes are
>   detected. This command does not exit until an interrupt is received.